# Label impulse plot in Gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot

I am currently plotting a series of impulse bars with Gnuplot

```
using 1:23 notitle with impulses lt 0 linecolor rgb "#C0C0C0" axis x1y2, \
using 1:24 notitle with impulses lt 0 linecolor rgb "#C0C0C0" axis x1y2, \
```

and I would like to label these impulse bars with identifying numbers at the top of each impulse. How can I adjust the above code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but you can always plot `with labels` to add labels on the plot at specified positions.